# Hibernate 4.3 with Informix JDBC 3 driver

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jdbc, informix

Hibernate 4.3 expects to be used with JDBC 4 drivers.
Unfortunately, some vendors (like IBM with Informix) do not yet provide a JDBC 4 driver, they are only JDBC 3 compliant.

Therefore, you will get errors in some cases, e.g. when inserting data to a BLOB you'll get:

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method com/informix/jdbc/IfxPreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(ILjava/io/InputStream;J)V is abstract

So why does Hibernate work as if JDBC 4 drivers for Informix were already available? Why did the Hibernate team not anticipate this problem?

Comment: Microsoft has a JDBC 4 driver: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774

Comment: you are completely right. I adapted the question such that it only mentions Informix now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple workaround for the mentioned errors concerning setBinaryStream: you have to write your own subclasses of Hibernate's dialects and then use these dialects, e.g. for Informix:

```
package at.rsf4j.core.db.hibernate.dialect;

import org.hibernate.dialect.InformixDialect;

/**
 * special dialect that asserts that Hibernate 4 works with a JDBC 3 Informix driver.
 * As soon as there is a JDBC 4 driver, this class can be deleted.
 */
public class InformixJdbc3Dialect extends InformixDialect {

    /**
     * this must return false as long as we use a JDBC 3.0 driver for Informix
     */
    @Override
    public boolean useInputStreamToInsertBlob() {
        return false;
    }



}
```

My question is: I can't possibly be the first person to notice these problems. Am I missing something, is there a better way to solve these problems? Otherwise I would expect this code to be part of Hibernate...

P.S. this solution only addresses the setBinaryStream problem, other possible errors due to old JDBC 3 drivers are not solved.